# How to fix the facebook login button w3 validator error

Tags: php, facebook, html, w3c-validation

In my project i have added fconnect button code as follows. I have used HTML 5.

```
<fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

My doctype declaration us as follows.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

When i use the above code i had a following error in w3 validator with HTML5.

Here  you can find the button code.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

line 219 column 24 - Error: Element fb:login-button not allowed as child of element li in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.

How to fix this error in HTML5. Thanks in advance.

Comment: child of element li ? would you like to show more code?

Comment: @Hemc- i have updated my code in my question itself. so check it now.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hehehe, it may sound stupid, but you can do this

```
<div id="your_valid_fb_login"></div>
<script>
$('#your_valid_fb_login').html('<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button><div id="status"></div>');
</script>
```